# How to use onSelect event in Kartik datePicker?

Tags: php, jquery, datepicker, yii2

I am using kartik `datePicker` in my site but whenever I try to use `onSelect` event the doesn't triggered I don't know what is the problem. I searched a lot but didn't find any solution.
This is my code:

```
<?php
                    echo DatePicker::widget([
                    'name' => 'check_issue_date',
                    'type' => DatePicker::TYPE_INLINE,
                    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select issue date ...', 'id' => 'date-picker'],
                    'pluginOptions' => [
                        'format' => 'dd-M-yyyy',
                        'todayHighlight' => false,
                        'onSelect' => 'function(dateText, inst) {
                            alert("hello");
                        }'
                    ]
                    ]);
?>
```

Comment: no error messages or anything in the js console?

Comment: try `onSelectDate`

Comment: @delboy1978uk no error messages nothing is in console even I tried with `onSelectDate`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at pluginEvents on this page http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/datepicker#settings

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo DatePicker::widget([
                            'id'=>'scheduleProject',
                            'name' => 'scheduleProject',                
                            'type' => DatePicker::TYPE_INLINE,
                            'language' => 'en',            
                            'pluginOptions' => [
                                'format' => 'M-dd-yyyy',
                                'startDate' => date(\Yii::$app->params['viewDateFormat']),
                                'todayHighlight' => true,
                                'todayBtn' => true, 

                            ],
                            'pluginEvents' =>[
                                "changeDate" => "function(e) {  alert(123)}",
                            ]    

                        ]);?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo DatePicker::widget([
'name' => 'check_issue_date',
'type' => DatePicker::TYPE_INLINE,
'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select issue date ...', 'id' => 'date-picker'],
'pluginOptions' => [
    'format' => 'dd-M-yyyy',
    'todayHighlight' => false,
    'onSelect' => 'function(dateText, inst) {
                            alert("hello");
                        }'
],
'pluginEvents' => [
    'onChange' => 'function(event) {
        console.log(event.date);
    }'
]
```

]);
?>

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).